# Rails - attribute? method's return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

I'm confused with rails' attribute? method.For example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :x
end
user = User.new
user.x = 0

user.x? #false
```

Why not `user.x? => true` for `0`?

When I dive into rails source code, in `active_support/core_ext/class/delegating_attributes.rb` it says:

```
define_method("#{name}?") { !!send("#{name}") } if options[:instance_reader] != false
```

and in `active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb`:

```
def self.#{name}?() !!#{name} end
```

Isn't `0 => true`?